# Selecting rows from left table that is related to rows in the right table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Giving Table I:

```
I1
I2
I3
I4
```

And the second table C:

```
C1
C2
C3
```

And the third CI:

```
I1 C2
I1 C3
I2 C2
I3 C2
I3 C3
I4 C2
I4 C3
```

Any idea of SQL request that gives only the row that is common to all of the first table, like the following result:

```
C2
```

For another set like this:

```
I1 C2
I1 C3
I2 C2
I3 C3
I4 C2
I4 C3
```

the result would be empty.
And For

```
I1
I2
I3
I4
I5
```

and

```
I1 C2
I1 C3
I2 C2
I3 C2
I3 C3
I4 C2
I4 C3
```

reuslt: empty

*see the discussion

Thank you.

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT [DISTINCT]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableC c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT 1 
                    FROM TableI i 
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT 1 FROM TableCI ci 
                                        WHERE   ci.I = i.I 
                                                AND ci.C = c.C
                                     )
                )
```

Or `GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT [DISTINCT]` as jarlh's suggestion

```
DECLARE @NumberI int = (SELECT count(*) FROM TableI)

SELECT c.C
FROM TableC c
INNER JOIN TableCI ci ON c.C = ci.C
INNER JOIN TableI i ON ci.I = i.I 
GROUP BY c.C
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ci.I) = @NumberI
```

Comment: I have `INNER JOIN TableI` to check ci.I must be in TableI

Comment: The second solution seem to works fine except if one element of the first table is not associated with any element in the second table, like:  I5 NULL

Comment: In this case how `COUNT(DISTINCT ci.I) = @NumberI`? it will not exist in result set.

Comment: It will not exist the the table IC but exist in table I and not associated with any element of table C, for that reason the result would be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:
WHERE EXISTS ( subquery )

Answer (score 0):

So you want to show the second column of table CI only when the value in this column is associated to all the records that exists in table I?

If that's the case, you can do like this:

```
select Col2 from  ( select Col2 , count(Col1) As Expr1 from CI group by Col2 ) A
where Expr1 = (select count(*) from I)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution and the basic premise is:
 
We want only those C records, for which the Count Distinct of their I records should be same as Count distinct of I records for the whole table

```
            select TBL.C, count(distinct TBL.I)
            from TBL
            group by TBL.C
            having count(distinct TBL.I)= (select count(distinct TBL.I) from TBL)
```

In Oracle, here is the Query and the result set

```
           with TBL 
            as
            (
            select 'I1' I,'C2' C from dual
            union all
            select 'I1','C3' from dual
            union all
            select 'I2','C2' from dual
            union all
            select 'I3','C2' from dual
            union all
            select 'I3','C3' from dual
            union all 
            select 'I4','C2' from dual
            union all
            select 'I4','C3' from dual
            )

            select TBL.C, count(distinct TBL.I)
            from TBL
            group by TBL.C
            having count(distinct TBL.I)= (select count(distinct TBL.I) from TBL)
```

Result Set:

```
    C2   4
```